# Python - Assigning 2 variables from one string

Tags: python, arrays, variable-assignment

**values** is an array; **eventTokens** is a string (first element of values). What does the double assignment do? (What are the values of eventToken1 & eventToken2?)

```
values = data.split("\x01")

eventTokens = values.pop(0)
eventToken1, eventToken2 = eventTokens
```

I've done an output task (on the Python source) that resulted in the following:

```
eventTokens is →☹
eventToken1 is →
eventToken2 is ☹
```

I concluded that the vars somehow split the initial string. However, if I tried compiling an (apparently) similar thing:

```
arr = ["some", "elements", "inarray"]
c = arr.pop(0)
a, b = c
print c
print a
print b
```

It resulted in an exception: *ValueError: too many values to unpack* .

Note: `print` is not a parameterized method in the tested environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Variable unpacking* is the Python's ability of multiple variable assignment in a single line. The constraint is that the iterable on right side of the expression have to be the same lenght of the variables on the left side. Otherwise you get a `too many` or `to little values to unpack` exception.

If you have a string of size 2 like `eventTokens` is supposed to be, you can then:

```
>>>a,b = 'ab'
>>>a
'a'
>>>b
'b'
```

This is very unsafe code. If somehow `eventTokens` grows larger than two elements the code will raise an exception an your program will be shut down.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

`c = arr.pop(0)` returns `"some"` here, but you are trying to assign the value to 2 variables in this step (where are there are 4 literals) hence,  `a, b = c` is failing.

Try this instead

```
arr = ["some", "elements", "inarray"]
c = arr.pop(0)
a, b = arr
print c
print a
print b
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. The reason you get the "too many values to unpack" error is because c has four characters, and you're trying to unpack it into just two variables. a, b, d, e = c would work.

Comment: @Jimothy I believe OP wants `a, b = arr` and not `a, b = c` , So _this_ example works

Comment: you're right. I should have said your explanation of why `a, b = c` gives an error is incorrect.

Comment: @Jimothy Thanks. Rectified.

Answer (score 3):

Since `eventTokens` is a string of length two, it can be unpacked into two single character strings:

```
>>> a, b = 'ab'
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
'b'
```

However, the number of characters in the string must match the number of variables being unpacked into:

```
>>> a, b = 'abcd'
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

---

Note that you can unpack into *one* variable!

```
>>> a, = 'x'
>>> a
'x'
>>> a, = 'xyz'
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```